# How to properly escape this string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which I am sending to an external print function.
I need to pad the string with backslashes so it prints properly.

Specifically, I need a method which would accept this example input:
`This is a string\nwith a line break\ta tab\rand a carriage return.`

and output:
`This is a string\\nwith a line break\\ta tab\\rand a carriage return.`

Do I need to brute force `Replace` every possible escape character with it's backslashed equivalent?

Tried:
`s.Replace("\\","\\\\")`
Doesn't work because it's looking for a backslash literal.

`s.Replace("\n","\\n")` obviously works, but what I'm looking for is a generic method.

Edit:
**Please don't suggest brute force methods, I understand it is no problem to implement such a method. My question was if there is a more universal approach.**

Comment: Your input isn't clear - do you mean you want to convert "a string with a newline" into "a string with a backslash followed by an n"?

Comment: @Jon Yes, exactly. I need to prepare my string for being double-escaped.

Comment: @Rotem What about @"This is a string\nwith a line break"? Have a great day :)

Comment: The C# literal string `"This is a string\nwith a line break"` has no backslashes in it - there is a newline character, to be sure, but no backslashes. There isn't anything to double-escape in it.

Comment: @Picrofo I am not generating the input myself, I receive it from an external method.

Comment: @David Perhaps the term double-escape is wrong. But the required output is still correct.

Comment: You can use `char.IsControl(char c)` to detect if the character is a control character, but I'm not sure how to convert that to a printable character.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
private static string EscapeLiterals(string input)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Takes input `"\tHello\r\n\tLiterals!"` and turns it into `"\\tHello\\r\\n\\tLiterals!"`

Works for any input - it will get you the escape sequence for anything.

Comment: Bravo, thank you! It's also worth mentioning that the classes exist in the `System.CodeDom` and `System.CodeDom.Compiler` namespaces.

Comment: Nice one, but be aware that for longer strings, this will insert "+" operators, newlines and indentation. I couldn't find a way to turn that off.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the function I use for this. I have used this in production code for years and it seems to hold up against all sorts of corner-cases.

```
/// <summary>
/// Escapes all characters in this string whose code is less than 32 using C/C#-compatible backslash escapes.
/// </summary>
public static string CLiteralEscape(this string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

    var result = new StringBuilder(value.Length + value.Length / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = value[i];
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\0': result.Append(@"\0"); break;
            case '\a': result.Append(@"\a"); break;
            case '\b': result.Append(@"\b"); break;
            case '\t': result.Append(@"\t"); break;
            case '\n': result.Append(@"\n"); break;
            case '\v': result.Append(@"\v"); break;
            case '\f': result.Append(@"\f"); break;
            case '\r': result.Append(@"\r"); break;
            case '\\': result.Append(@"\\"); break;
            case '"': result.Append(@"\"""); break;
            default:
                if (c >= ' ')
                    result.Append(c);
                else // the character is in the 0..31 range
                    result.AppendFormat(@"\x{0:X2}", (int) c);
                break;
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is what I would call he brute force approach mentioned in the question - never the less upvoted for listing unit test cases :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple replaces to enforce that replace of the whitespaces with readable control chars:

```cs
s = s.Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\t", "\\t");
```

However you cannot double the backslashes so simple as you think because the chars are already converted in the memory with its binary values. So you need to replace every char by hand.

Comment: I specifically stated that I know that this works and that I am looking for a method that takes care of all control characters.

Comment: Dito in the first version of my answer I made an mistake.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but it is a brute force method which I specifically said I am not looking for.

Comment: The point about brute force came later, but I see there no other solution. There is a quiet limited range of whitespace chars which can be *escaped* like you want.